# Excel Spreadsheet Manipulaltion using R program

Tags: r, excel

I was wondering is it possible for R to manipulate sheets in excel?
For example in an excel spreadsheet I have 3 different sheets...if I want to find the average/mean of each row of a particular column and place the output in a different sheet...would this be possible? How would I go about doing it?....Would it be wise to use XLConnect as the source of my functions or a different package?

Comment: yes, use XLConnect. The [vignettes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) have all the information you need.

Comment: The choices are outlined here: http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows

Comment: You can also use the R package RDCOMclient.